# How many goals did Cristiano Ronaldo score prior to the year 2020?

Tags: football

How many goals did Cristiano Ronaldo score prior to the year 2020?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Goal.com](https://www.goal.com/en-us/news/ronaldo-messi-who-has-scored-more-goals/1sqx0a7j3sifj1wxq6fy66civ6) Ronaldo scored 740 goals.

[image: goal comparison]